# Как настроить колонку в xlsx?

Tags: php, csv, xlsx

В `php` формируется `csv`, в одной из колонок есть такой текст:  `7-8` или `14-15`.
Когда `csv` добавляется в `xlsx` путём создания вручную нового `xlsx`, потом `Данные->Получить данные из файла csv`, то в колонке где находится текст `7-8`, заменяется таким текстом:  `07.08.2020` или `14.15.2020`.
Как это можно настроить, чтобы `7-8` не заменялось на `07.08.2020`?